# Whats the total combination of the below categories

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have 5 categories - A, B, C, D & E and each of these categories have sub categories like following

A - { a, b}

B - { c, d, e}

C - { f, g }

D - { h , i}

E - { j, k ,l}

I want to find the total combinations(ones+doubles+trebles+fours+fives) of the above system without repetitions

In each combinations, selecting elements from same sub category is not allowed like {Aa, Ab} cannot be in one combination

For Example
Combination of one's will be like below

Aa

Ab

Bc

....so on we have 12 such combinations for ones

Combination of two's

Aa , Bc

Ab , Bc,

Cf , Di

..... So on we will have some number of combinations
Here we cannot have {Aa,Ab} in one of the combinations.  {Aa,Ab} is not a valid combination

Combination of three's

Aa, Bc, Cf

Bc, Dh, Ej

.....So on 
Here we cannot have {Aa,Ab,Bc} in one of the combinations.  {Aa,Ab,Bc} is not a valid combination , you must choose from different categories

Combination of fours'

Aa,Bc,Cf,Dh

Aa,Bc,Cf,Di

Aa,Bc,Cg,Dh

.......So on
Here we cannot have {Aa,Ab,Bc,Cf} in one of the combinations.  {Aa,Ab,Bc, Cf} is not a valid combination , you must choose from different categories

Combination of five's

Aa,Bc,Cf,Dh,Ej

Aa,Bc,Cf,Dh,El

..... So On 
Here also elements from same category should not be in a combination

I want to find the total number of combinations i.e 
Total = No of Combinations of { one's + two's + three's + four's + five's}

Similarly if I have large number of categories like 15 instead of 5, Any generalized formula to calculate the number of combinations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your subcategories equivalent to elements? The notation is a bit unclear; working under this assumption, what you can do is add a subcategory to each category that represents "not choosing" that category. So we would have $A = \{a,b,0\}, B = \{c,d,e,0\}$, etc. For example, to represent choosing $\{Ab,Cg\}$, we would consider this equivalent to $\{Ab,B0,Cg,D0,E0\}$.

Then choosing any combination is just choosing exactly one element from each of your new category. This can be done through straightforward application of the multiplication rule; in this case, you would get $3 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 = 432$ valid choices.

Comment: Thanks, To make it clear the subcategories {a,b,c,d,e,f...} are all unique elements and are not equivalent to main category {A,B,C,D} i.e A ≠ a

Comment: Okay great, that matches my interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

In the first category you have 3 choices (Aa, Ab, none). Similarly for the other categories there are 4,3,3,4 choices. Hence there are $3*4*3*3*4-1=431$ combinations. $1$ is subtracted to cancel the empty set which is neither a one, double, treble, four, fives.

Answer (score 0):

$A={2}, B=3,C=2,D=2,E=3$ amount of subcategories

For doubles we choose from 5 categories 2 categories(combinations) $=10$ and multiply amount of subcategories in it: $A\cdot B + A\cdot C +A\cdot D + A\cdot E 
 +B\cdot C +B\cdot D+B\cdot E+C\cdot D+C\cdot E+D\cdot E=2\cdot3+2\cdot2+...+2\cdot3=57.$
For triples we choose from 5 categories 3 categories(combinations) $=10$ and multiply amount of subcategories in it... and so on